# Server-side Facebook authentication from a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to authenticate a user from chrome extension through the server side facebook authentication method?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using OAuth 2 authentication using a custom library like [this one](http://smus.com/oauth2-chrome-extensions/)